# Windows Communication Foundation parameter inspection

Tags: wcf

How can one monitor Windows Communication Foundation calls and say log to a text file using the IParameterInspector while using Internet Information Services hosting.

Comment: Did you look at this [WCF Extensibility - IParameterInspector](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/04/25/wcf-extensibility-iparameterinspector/)?

Comment: Yes i did, the issue is with how i call / startup the logging to say a text file. In  any self hosting it works but with IIS i cannot log to text file for example